# DateTime destroys View

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

I have a pretty basic/standard MVC project I'm building up. Everything in it works fine (Fig 1) until I add a DateTime object to my Model (Fig 2), at which point the View for that Model gets very distorted, and won't display any information (Fig 3). See the entry in my SQL Database for the related DateTime object (Fig 4).

I am left to assume it's something to do specifically with the DateTime data type, but I'm not sure What might be causing this or what could I try for troubleshooting.

Fig 1:

[image]

Fig 2:

[image]

Fig 3:

[image]

Fig 4:

[image]

Code from my View as asked:

```
    @model TKOPOC.Models.SubmitEIDs

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@* Model Update Alert *@
@if(Model.isVerify){ <h1><span style="color: red;">VERIFY YOUR CHANGES, THEN CLICK SUBMIT</span></h1> }

 @*Search Box*@ 
@if(!Model.isVerify)
{ 
    using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "EightID", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        <p>
            Find by name or EID: @Html.TextBox("searchString", ViewBag.CurrentFilter as string)
            <input type="submit" value="Search" />
        </p>
    }   
    <p>
        @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
    </p>
}

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("EID", "Index", new { sortOrder=ViewBag.EIDSortParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Name", "Index", new { sortOrder=ViewBag.NameSortParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Email", "Index", new { sortOrder=ViewBag.EmailSortParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Physical", "Index", new { sortOrder=ViewBag.PhysicalSortParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink("Admin", "Index", new { sortOrder=ViewBag.AdminSortParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink(" Maint", "Index", new { sortOrder=ViewBag.MaintSortParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink(" Cab", "Index", new { sortOrder=ViewBag.CabSortParm, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.ActionLink(" Mills", "Index", new { sortOrder=ViewBag.MillSortParam, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter })
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model.EightIDsPagedList) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.EID)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Physical)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Admin)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Maint)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cab)
        </td>
        <td>
            @if (item.Admin | item.Maint)
            {
                <text>All</text>
            }
            else
            { 
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Mills.Count)
            }            
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.EightIDID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.EightIDID }) |
            @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.EightIDID })
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>

<p>&nbsp</p>

@* Paging *@
<div>
    Page @(Model.EightIDsPagedList.PageCount < Model.EightIDsPagedList.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.EightIDsPagedList.PageNumber)
    of @Model.EightIDsPagedList.PageCount

    @if (Model.EightIDsPagedList.HasPreviousPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("<<", "Index", new { page = 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter  })
        @Html.Raw(" ");
        @Html.ActionLink("< Prev", "Index", new { page = Model.EightIDsPagedList.PageNumber - 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter  })
    }
    else
    {
        @:<<
        @Html.Raw(" ");
        @:< Prev 
    }
        @for (var x = 1; x < Model.EightIDsPagedList.PageCount; x++)
    {
        if (Model.EightIDsPagedList.PageNumber == x)
        {
            @x;
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.ActionLink(Convert.ToString(x), "Index", new { page = x, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter = ViewBag.CurrentFilter });
        }
    }

    @if (Model.EightIDsPagedList.HasNextPage)
    {
        @Html.ActionLink("Next >", "Index", new { page = Model.EightIDsPagedList.PageNumber + 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter  })
        @Html.Raw(" ");
        @Html.ActionLink(">>", "Index", new { page = Model.EightIDsPagedList.PageCount, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter  })
    }
    else
    {
        @:Next >
        @Html.Raw(" ")
        @:>>
    }
</div>

<p>&nbsp</p>

<table border="0">
    <tr>        
            @if (!Model.isVerify)
            {                        
                using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "EightID", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
                {
                    <td>
                    <input type="file" name="file" required />
                    <input type="submit" name="Verify" value="Verify" />
                    </td>
                }             
            }            
            else
            {
                using (Html.BeginForm("Submit", "EightID", FormMethod.Post, new { NewEIDs = Model.EightIDs }))
                {       
                    <td>             
                    <input type="submit" name="Submit Changes" value="Submit" />
                    </td>
                }
                using (Html.BeginForm("Cancel", "EightID", FormMethod.Post))
                {
                    <td>
                    <input type="submit" name="Cancel" value="Cancel" />
                    </td>
                }
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Edit:

After some more debugging through the view, I've found *where* the issue occurs, just not *why* - after the table headers, we come down to the foreach() loop where the DisplayFor happens. Here, the program hits foreach. Then Model.EightIDsPagedList. Then "in". But then it never comes into var or item and just skips the loop entirely. When I removed the DateTime items in question, the program enters the loop as you would expect it to and continues execution all the way down.

Comment: You should include your view code, a `.cshtml` file if using razor.

Comment: Do yo uhave a column for the DateTime? It looks like you are making it item zero, but there is no header for the column.  "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"

Comment: I'm not exactly intimate with formatting enforcement, but suffice to say that this problem occurred before I added that part on there. I was under the impression that the 0 had to do with the way it was formatted, rather than something to do with what sounds like is a column assignment?  But if the column you're asking about existing is in the database, then yes, there's a column for that with an entry in the first row

Comment: Also interesting is that in the SQL Server I set it as a DateTime2(0) hoping it would remove the precision in seconds (saw that 7 did 7 second digits, 4 would do 4 digit precision, etc), but it still comes up as yyyy-mm-dd 00:00:00.0000000

Comment: Also, you should include the code where you are populating your model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you get a null reference exception anywhere? Do you have a value in the DateTime column when you run the example? Your SQL seems to be nullable but your property is not. You could try these options:

1. Making that a `DateTime?` (nullable DateTime) in the code.
2. Make sure you have a value in SQL
3. Making the SQL column not nullable (which will guarantee option 2).

Let us know if that helps.

Comment: Let me make it nullable in the code and check. I wanted to make it nullable in the database because I'm working with a partial set of data in the test environment and wanted to avoid having to populate 100+ entries by hand.  As for any exceptions, I don't appear to be getting any at all - it just swallows whatever issue is coming up it would seem

Comment: So as it turns out, making that DateTime nullable got me pretty far. Now I just have to work on turning mm/dd/yyyy HH:MM:SS AM/PM into mm/dd/yyyy. I originally had a decoration on it as seen in the screen shots above, but it doesn't seem to like that format conversion very much, so I'll play around with it. But for all intents & purposes, it's essentially working now !

Comment: Hey I'm glad that helped. Not all model properties are nullable. In this case it seems to be due to the fact that DateTime is a struct and not a class. Since structs in c# are value types (as opposed to reference types), they are not nullable by default. You have to make them nullable explicitly if you want them to be nullable. Care to accept my answer then? If you still need help with the date format, you could post a new question and give a bit more detail there.

Comment: Answer accepted - and I got the formatting figured out not long after posting the comment :)

Comment: Thanks! Cool you got the date format figured out too. Keep it up